# Dynamically add ID to header based on header name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Jquery for a small project and I have run into an issue.

I'm trying to create a small script that will look at a page, and automatically assign an ID to H1 headers based on the header text, i.e:

```
<h1> This is a Test </h1>
```

to

```
<h1 id="This_is_a_Test"> This is a Test</h1>
```

I've been able to select every H1, but I haven't been able to modify the ID based on the header text.

```
var $headers = $('.body h1);
$headers.attr("id", not sure exactly how to pass headers text to this?);
```

I'm obviously very much a novice, but would appreciate some help in this!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a jQuery's [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) with the [callback option](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) to read the text of the headers, converting it to snake case, and setting it as the `id`:

```js
var $headers = $('.body h1');
$headers.attr("id", function() {
  return $(this)
    .text() // get the h1 text
    .trim() // remove spaces from start and the end
    .toLowerCase() // optional
    .replace(/\s/g, '_'); // convert all spaces to underscores
});

console.log($headers[0]);
console.log($headers[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
  <h1>This is a Test </h1>
  
  <h1>This is a another Test </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ori! This worked perfectly for me, and the comments help me digest what is happening. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this for every `h1` element you have in your page you can do something like that:

```js
$(function() {
  $('h1').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id', $(this).text().replace(/ /g, '_'))
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Some text</h1>
<h1>Some other text</h1>
```

The function will take every `h1` element, [for each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) it will set the value of the `id` attribute (using the [`attr` function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)) to the [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) of that `h1` element (while changing every space with underscore).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to generate the `id` by using the `text` method for `h1`.

```
var $headers = $('.body h1');  // select the element
var text = $headers.text();    // get the text of the element
var id = text.trim().split(' ').join('_');  // split by space and join using _
$headers.attr("id", id);
```